# How to toggle Signature help & intellisense VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have VS Code on Win8.1.

I really don't like how the [signature box](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_signature-help) opens up over the surrounding code in the editor. I do like the intellisense box. On the page (link above) it says `Ctrl+Shift+Space` to manually trigger signature help. **But how can I close it**? The problem is that it opens up without me triggering it.

I know I can close it by moving the cursor out from the function block. But that is a pain to have to do that all the time. I wish `Ctrl+Shift+Space` could toggle the box.

I remember when I used Visual Studio. There was a key-short-cut to toggle or to get opacity on the boxes. That was great. Is that possible in VS Code?

It is for JavaScript/React (if that's important)

---

EDIT:
I found an answer on Reddit that don't give me the good solution Visual Studio has. But it makes the box a bit transparent. But it is always transparent. Here is the solution for the half-way-workaround (cut-and-past from the reddit-post, user: **tgreen7**):

I found a way to do this in settings. if you go here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference and search for "editorSuggestWidget.background" that is the setting you are looking to change.

So for example my background was originally the hex color: #21252B

And I changed my settings like so:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorSuggestWidget.background": "#21252BAA"
}
```

and now my suggestion window has opacity. You can adjust the last two digits of the hex number to get your desired transparency (opacity).

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>escape</kbd> will close it, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to get it back.

---

If you want a **toggle** try this with whatever keybinding you want:

```
   {
      "key": "ctrl+shift+space",   // whatever, even "escape"
      "command": "editor.action.triggerParameterHints",
      "when": "editorHasSignatureHelpProvider && editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
      "key": "ctrl+shift+space",  // use same keybinding as above here fro toggle
      "command": "closeParameterHints",
      "when": "editorHasSignatureHelpProvider && editorTextFocus && parameterHintsVisible"
    },
```